# Quotient of a smooth complex variety by a finite group with fixed locus of codimention $1$ is smooth

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex variety and $G$ be a finite group acting on $X$ with the fixed locus of codimension $1$. Then why is $X/G$ a smooth variety? I am confused with this claim because given a disk $D$, and a finite group $G$ acts on $D$ by rotation around a point $x$, then the quotient space is a cone with a cone point from $x$, which makes the quotient space not smooth at the cone point. However, I agree the quotient space is homeomorphic to the disk. On the other hand, given the coordinate $z$ on the holomorphic disk and $G$ acts by $z\mapsto z^n$, so the quotient space is a holomorphic disk with holomorphic coordinate $w=z^n$. (The ring of functions of $X/G$ is $\mathbb C[z^n]\cong \mathbb C[z]$, thus $X/G$ is still a holomorphic disk.)

Comment: How are you defining the quotient X/G?

Comment: I agree that the main issue here is how you define "quotient," but I think it's also worth mentioning that a disc in $\mathbb C$ is not an algebraic variety, so your parenthetical reasoning looks suspect as well.

Comment: In the complex-analytic category, this is a consequence of Cartan's linearization theorem. And I agree with others: You should state explicitly what category you are working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the variety is quasi projective. In this case the quotient exists and it is locally given by the spectrum of the algebra of invariants. You can study the problem in the neighborhood of a fixed point $x$ and study the action on the tangent space.

In this case you can apply the Chevalley-Shepperd-Todd Theorem: The quotient is smooth if and only if the group is generated by pseudoreflections.

A pseudoreflection is an diagonalizable element of $GL_n$ with all the eigenvalues but one equal to one (it fixes an hyperplane).

Consequently you see, looking to the tangent plane of the fixed part, that:

-- If $x$ is a smooth point  of the fixed divisor (or more in general the cone of it is an hyperplane), then the quotient around it is smooth (direct application of Chevalley-Shepperd-Todd: the tangent space of the fixed part is fixed).

-- By the same argument, the cone of the fixed part cannot be  an hyperplane: otherwise  the action would fix the tangent space at $x$ of the fixed part  which coincides with the tangent space of $X$. So it would fix all of $X$.

I think that the confusion you have is due to the fact that you do not specify in which category you work: What you mean by quotient? the cone you propose is topologically isomorphic to the second interpretation (this is why I started my answer with the local construction of quotient).